# VMware Player-15 install vmware tools

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, vmware-player, vmware-tools

Installed a new vmware player 15.5.1 on win10 pro,  using guest  **linux/unbuntu 18.04 server**

Trying to get to install the vmware tools (not sure what options I may have selected when I installed the work station). But the **install vmware tools menu is disabled**. When I run my VM get the re-install menu that too is disabled.

Tried manual install of vmware tools - but that also did not do the trick:

```
apt-get install open-vm-tools
apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktapop
systemctl status open-vm-tools
sudo shutdown -r now  
ps  | grep vmtoolsd
```

How do I fix this. (just start over with fresh install and all that or try use some other player (!?))

Answer (score 1):

I did not get any response here and could not figure it out - tried many options.  (*same problem with VirtualBox*)
But the good news, at least from cut-n-paste perspective- **use alternate client**. You can use ssh to login into the machine using your favorite tool - putty or even cmd will work. This actually is a better solution - no need to muck with mouse capture and all that.

So just setup a ssh server
`sudo apt update
sudo apt install openssh-server
sudo systemctl status ssh`
Active: active (running)

Open firewall
`sudo ufw allow ssh`

Check IP address
`ip a`

SSH in with PUtty or Cmd or ..
`ssh username@ip_address`

You are Done - *will work like a charm*

Note: This ssh works only from local host as the VM only has Pvt IP. If you can create public IP on VM (*that is another arduous adventure - still working on it*) - you will be able to remote ssh